# How Often Is The Azure Functions Beta Host Updated on the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm using the Azure Functions v2 in a project that I've started recently and I'm trying to use a proxy to redirect a request to /.well-known to one of my functions.

Proxies do not work on Azure Functions v2 ([as stated here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Azure-Functions-runtime-2.0-known-issues)). They have now been fixed in release [v2.0.11737-alpha](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.11737-alpha) but the Azure Portal is still using [v2.0.11651.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.11651-alpha)

Does anyone know how long it takes after a beta release is created in GitHub for it to be available in the Azure portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It normally just takes a few days, but this particular release was cancelled. See https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/105 for details. A new one should start later this week. See https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/106.

For generally, please follow the announcement repo issue tracker for all information and status about upcoming releases.